# C# web app not connecting to on premise SQL Server through Azure hybrid Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

Steps that I've taken so far

1. I've disabled the firewall and configured the SQL Server to allow remote   connections
2. Verified if the hybrid connection manager has the connection established
3. Modified the connection string to specify the TCP ports

Please let me know if you have any further suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you include the connection string you're using, and what error you're getting back. Are you able to connect using SSMS or SQLCMD?

Comment: Where the on premise server is located? Can you share the connection string? If the server is part of corporate network then you won't be able to access it outside network without proper permissions provided by the network admins.

Comment: In what way is it 'not connecting'? At the very least you should find an error and post it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the replies, I've finally figured it out.The mistake i was making was that i  was specifying the SQL Server Name AND port number(433 in my case) ONLY while deplying to azure and in my code behind the connection string only had the server name mentioned.

[image]

However when I updated the connection string in my code behind to include the TCP port, i was able to successfully run the app in conjunction with the Hybrid connection to query results from the SQL Server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Recently I also worked on Azure hybrid connection and have made a list of all the possible problems that I faced. One of the following may be the cause:

- Hybrid Connection may only work with Default Instance of SQL Server and may fail in case of using a Named Instance. Even if the named instance is configured to use static TCP port yet might not work with the Hybrid Connection.
  The possible reason might be either your named instance might be listening on the same TCP port as your default instance. As hybrid connection uses port for communication so in case when multiple instances are listening on the same port then hybrid connection might communicate to any of the one regardless of what instance you have supplied in your named instance.
- In order for hybrid connection to work you need to enable TLS 1.0 on your on premises machine for both server and client. You need to add following registery value (if not already added):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
```

- The hybrid connection will only work if the connection string uses SQL Authentication i.e., specifying the username and password in the connection string. Thus you can not use Windows Authentication.
- Although you do not need to open any firewall ports for inbound connectivity yet you are required to allow outbound connections to the following list of ports:
  9350 – 9354,
  5671,
  80,
  443
- Azure hybrid connection requires Windows 8/Windows Server 2012 or later to work with. The reason for this is that hybrid connection uses Web sockets that are not supported in the earlier windows version than these. Although you can use the classic hybrid connection (now depricated) to work with the earlier Windows.
- It is preferred to use the Fully-Qualified machine names for the endpoint and not the IP address. In cases where the IP of your machine is unlikely to chnage there it might have no effect but in cases where the IP might change, you shuold use the machine name and let the HCM handle everything else for you.

Also a very comprehensive walkthrough of creating a hybrid connection can be find  [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hybrid-connection-on-premises-sql-server-tayyab-nasir/?trackingId=Y%2BMIHUNA3c6OV%2FdLzdT%2FaQ%3D%3D)

Hope this solves your problem.