# Connecting to On-Premises SQL Server from API in Azure App Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-hybrid-connections

I am trying to connect to an on-premises SQL Server from my API which i have deployed to Azure App Service. I have established a Azure Hybrid Connection to connect between on-premises SQL and Azure. I created a connection string which included username and password as that of a local login i created in the On-Premises server. This is allowing me to connect.

Connection String:

```
Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

However i want to connect to the server using windows authentication. My System account has access on the server, but when using connection string as -

```
Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=SSPI;User=;Password=;
```

Or

```
Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

It is giving error as

> "*Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be
>   used with Windows authentication.*"

Please suggest how to use windows mode of authentication while forming connection string to the on-premises SQL Server from Azure App Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Hybrid Connection does not appear to support Active Directory and hence Windows Authentication will not work. See note about sql auth being required in Official MS documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview

Also, look at the following SO question where one of the answers details common issues faced this setup:

[C# web app not connecting to on premise SQL Server through Azure hybrid Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745650/c-sharp-web-app-not-connecting-to-on-premise-sql-server-through-azure-hybrid-con)

You are unlikely to get around this, especially if you are hosting your app as a web app.

Comment: Right, Windows Authentication won't work since it relies on Kerberos, which means domain join for the machine that hosts your Web App (not applicable in App Service).