# Azure Web App Hybrid Connection with Windows Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-hybrid-connections

We're running into an issue connecting an Azure Web App to an on premise SQL Server using Windows Authentication via a Hybrid Connection.  We're able to get it working using SQL Server authentication, but the issue we're facing is that we also want to connect to a Tabular Model, which only allows connections using Windows Authentication.

I know Microsoft supports Windows Authentication in similar services (e.g. Power BI / Data Gateway connections).  Has anyone gotten this to work, one way or another?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I missed this on my search through Stack Overflow, but I just found this, which has already been answered: [Connecting to On-Premises SQL Server from API in Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767779/connecting-to-on-premises-sql-server-from-api-in-azure-app-service)